# Seaborn exception because of color argument

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to plot something that should look like this:

[image]

For a reproducible example let me provide some Toy Data:

```
    toy_data

    Principal Gender loan_status
    0           1      0     PAIDOFF
    1           1      1     PAIDOFF
    2           1      0     PAIDOFF
    3           1      1     PAIDOFF
    4           1      0     PAIDOFF
    341  0.714286      0  COLLECTION
    342         1      0  COLLECTION
    343  0.714286      0  COLLECTION
    344         1      0  COLLECTION
    345         1      0  COLLECTION
```

Or alternatively:

```
'{"Principal":{"0":1.0,"1":1.0,"2":1.0,"3":1.0,"4":1.0,"341":0.7142857143,"342":1.0,"343":0.7142857143,"344":1.0,"345":1.0},"Gender":{"0":0.0,"1":1.0,"2":0.0,"3":1.0,"4":0.0,"341":0.0,"342":0.0,"343":0.0,"344":0.0,"345":0.0},"loan_status":{"0":"PAIDOFF","1":"PAIDOFF","2":"PAIDOFF","3":"PAIDOFF","4":"PAIDOFF","341":"COLLECTION","342":"COLLECTION","343":"COLLECTION","344":"COLLECTION","345":"COLLECTION"}}'
```

My code is the following:

```
bins=np.linspace(toy_data.Principal.min(), toy_data.Principal.max(), 10)
g = sns.FacetGrid(toy_data, col="Gender", hue="loan_status", palette="Set1", col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.hist, 'Principal', bins=bins, ec="k")
g.axes[-1].legend()
plt.show()
```

Which returns the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-ef89846d23ff> in <module>()
      1 bins=np.linspace(toy_data.Principal.min(), toy_data.Principal.max(), 10)
      2 g = sns.FacetGrid(toy_data, col="Gender", hue="loan_status", palette="Set1", col_wrap=2)
----> 3 g.map(plt.hist, 'Principal', bins=bins, ec="k")
      4 
      5 g.axes[-1].legend()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in map(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    741 
    742             # Draw the plot
--> 743             self._facet_plot(func, ax, plot_args, kwargs)
    744 
    745         # Finalize the annotations and layout

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in _facet_plot(self, func, ax, plot_args, plot_kwargs)
    825 
    826         # Draw the plot
--> 827         func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)
    828 
    829         # Sort out the supporting information

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, normed, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3130                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   3131                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 3132                       stacked=stacked, normed=normed, data=data, **kwargs)
   3133     finally:
   3134         ax._hold = washold

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1853                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1854                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1855             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1856 
   1857         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
   6502             color = mcolors.to_rgba_array(color)
   6503             if len(color) != nx:
-> 6504                 raise ValueError("color kwarg must have one color per dataset")
   6505 
   6506         # If bins are not specified either explicitly or via range,

ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error message and what I should do to correct it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with this dataset. Please give us easy-to-import data. E.g. output of `toy_data.to_json()`

Comment: I did as you asked.  Please see my edited post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we got:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

toy_data = pd.read_json('{"Principal":{"0":1.0,"1":1.0,"2":1.0,"3":1.0,"4":1.0,"341":0.7142857143,"342":1.0,"343":0.7142857143,"344":1.0,"345":1.0},"Gender":{"0":0.0,"1":1.0,"2":0.0,"3":1.0,"4":0.0,"341":0.0,"342":0.0,"343":0.0,"344":0.0,"345":0.0},"loan_status":{"0":"PAIDOFF","1":"PAIDOFF","2":"PAIDOFF","3":"PAIDOFF","4":"PAIDOFF","341":"COLLECTION","342":"COLLECTION","343":"COLLECTION","344":"COLLECTION","345":"COLLECTION"}}')

bins=np.linspace(toy_data.Principal.min(), toy_data.Principal.max(), 10)
g = sns.FacetGrid(toy_data, col="Gender", hue="loan_status", palette="Set1", col_wrap=2, height=4)
g.map(plt.hist, 'Principal', bins=bins, ec="k")
g.axes[-1].legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Results]

---

I did not get any error. Tell us what versions of matplotlib and seaborn you are using. Looks like they are incompatible.

Comment: You are right. I updated both packages and the problem was solved.  Thank you!